# Como puedo hacer para que las series de mi gráfica Amchart se basen en la misma escala

Tags: javascript, java, amcharts

No tengo muchos conocimientos de Amcharts y me he visto en la obligación de usarlo. Necesito una gráfica que me compare tres valores de precio respecto a una inversión, valor máximo, valor de cierre y valor mínimo.

He conseguido ponerlos todos en una gráfica pero me ocurre un problema un tanto curioso y es que las distintas series que he añadido se escalan en función de sus propios valores, es decir, estando en una misma gráfica y teniendo los valores correctos un valor menor en ocasiones se posiciona por encima de uno mayor ya que en las escalas no son las mismas.

Me gustaría poner todas las series respecto a la misma escala, agradecería mucho la ayuda, adjunto el código de javascript que estoy usando y una captura del problema.

```
// Create series
function createAxisAndSeries(field, name, opposite, bullet) {
    var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    series.dataFields.valueY = field;
    series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
    series.strokeWidth = 2;
    series.yAxis = valueAxis;
    series.name = name;
    series.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
    series.tensionX = 0.8;

    var interfaceColors = new am4core.InterfaceColorSet();

    switch (bullet) {
        case "triangle":
            var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
            bullet.width = 12;
            bullet.height = 12;
            bullet.horizontalCenter = "middle";
            bullet.verticalCenter = "middle";

            var triangle = bullet.createChild(am4core.Triangle);
            triangle.stroke = interfaceColors.getFor("background");
            triangle.strokeWidth = 2;
            triangle.direction = "top";
            triangle.width = 12;
            triangle.height = 12;
            break;
        case "rectangle":
            var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
            bullet.width = 10;
            bullet.height = 10;
            bullet.horizontalCenter = "middle";
            bullet.verticalCenter = "middle";
            var rectangle = bullet.createChild(am4core.Rectangle);
            rectangle.stroke = interfaceColors.getFor("background");
            rectangle.strokeWidth = 2;
            rectangle.width = 10;
            rectangle.height = 10;
            break;

        default:
            var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
            bullet.circle.stroke = interfaceColors.getFor("background");
            bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
            break;
    }

    valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 1;
    valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeWidth = 2;
    valueAxis.renderer.line.stroke = series.stroke;
    valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = series.stroke;
    valueAxis.renderer.opposite = opposite;
    valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
}


createAxisAndSeries("cierre", "Cierre", false, "circle");
createAxisAndSeries("apertura", "Apertura", true, "triangle");
createAxisAndSeries("maximo", "Mínimo", true, "rectangle");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Ya encontré la respuesta,hay que sacar este fragmento de código

```
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
```

de la función createAxisAndSeries y pasarle la variable a la función como parámetro, de esta manera se genera solo una abscisa y todas las series se escalan en función de los mismos valores.